# Ksoap2 returns anytype{} instead of null

Tags: android, ksoap2

This is my asynchronous code

```
@Override
protected SoapObject doInBackground(String... params) {
try {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("ID", "0014");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.implicitTypes = false;
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    SoapFault fault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
    System.out.println("fault in getdata : " + fault);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    System.out.println("result in getdata : " + result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println("Exception : " + e.toString());
    }
    return result;
    }
```

And my response is

```
result in getdata : Getesponse{GetResult=anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType
{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; 
diffgram=anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{Table1=anyType{Name=Sathish1; Subject=anyType{}; ID=0014; }; }; }; }; }
```

Here I want subject as `null` instead of `anyType{}`. Is there any better idea other than checking using `if` statement friends?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you later parse the result, use `getPrimitiveProperty` instead of `getProperty`.
It is essentially the same, but fixes this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

String code = soapObject.getProperty("Code").toString().replace("anyType{}", "");

Comment: Please also provide an explanation

Answer (score 0):

To get a response you better use:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

OR another way, but you need to enable debugging beforehand:

```
androidHttpsTransport.debug = true;
```

here is how I make call and get a response:

```
private String makeCall(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope) {
    HttpsTransportSE mHttpsTransport = getAndroidHttpsTransport();

    try {
        mHttpsTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.logError(TAG, e);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Logger.logError(TAG, e);
    } finally {
        Logger.logDebug(TAG, "Request dump is ");
    }

    return mHttpsTransport.responseDump;
}
```

Comment: this returns `XmlPullParserException` friend

Comment: Show me the URL you're using to init your `transport`.